# Convert factor variables to numeric with levels in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of factor `a b a b c b ...`

Now I want to convert it to numeric, but with a = 2, b = 3, c = 1

I tried:

`as.numeric (my_vector, levels (c(2,3,1)))`

but it does not work. The error is `unused argument levels`

What is the correct way to convert?

Thanks

Comment: Try `factor(my_vector, labels = c(2, 3, 1))` or more safely would be `factor(my_vector, levels = letters[1:3], labels = c(2,3,1))`

Comment: or `as.numeric(factor(my_vector, levels=c("c", "a", "b"), ordered=TRUE))` to get a numeric vector

Comment: Yes, they are correct, thanks both of you